# Solr-4.4 port to .net using iKVM.net

Tags: java, .net, solr

i wanted to use Solr on shared hosting, as a .net port of Solr is not available so trying to do using iKVM.

Anybody got any converted & working copy of Solr4.4 using IKVM. After googling i found following links.

> http://bugsquash.blogspot.in/2011/02/running-solr-on-net.html
>
> http://dovetailsoftware.com/clarify/kmiller/2010/07/02/using-the-tika-java-library-in-your-net-application-with-ikvm/

being a .net guy i am bit confused what all .jars to be ported and what are other additional steps. I also wanted to know, Would there be any performance issues after that?

Comment: What have you tried? Fork https://github.com/mausch/SolrIKVM and update the jars, it's really easy to do. Also, the proper place to ask this is https://github.com/mausch/SolrIKVM/issues

Comment: actually i checked your blog and github before. actually i am looking for asp.net mode. i checked .bat file on github, but mentioned files are not available in solr4.4, there is no solr.jar. only  a war file. so my prime question is what all JARS should i convert and what other changes needs to done on asp.net to trigger the SOLR.

Comment: Unpack the WAR file, replace all the JAR files. If you're not familiar with this, consider it an opportunity to learn (everyone needs to have a basic understanding of Java concepts).

Comment: Cool i was going on right path, i have extracted WAR, i will try to port all JARS in this package using ikvm.net now.  i will try to figure out what all other changes required on .net side to get it work, Thanks.

Comment: Great! Let's keep the conversation on github.